# Como atualizar hora automaticamente usando strftime

Tags: php, javascript

Estou colocando hora e data pra ta exibindo no meu site, estou fazendo assim:

```
echo utf8_encode(strftime("%X - %m %B, %Y" ))  ;
```

Mas a hora esta estatica so atualizando quando recarrega a pagina, queria saber como faço para ela ficar atualizando normalmente, como se fosse um relogio mesmo,
acho que deve ser com javascript. Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, para isso é necessário fazer com JavaScript. As requisições HTTP não guardam estados no servidor (*stateless*) e, por isso, o script PHP deixa de ser executado após retornar a resposta à requisição. Desta forma, apenas será exibido o horário (do servidor) que foi executado o código.

**JavaScript**

Solução em JavaScript retirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229022/how-to-show-current-time-in-javascript-in-the-format-hhmmss):

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Nada mais é que uma função que recupera os valores de hora, minuto e segundo através dos métodos `getHours`, `getMinutes` e `getSeconds` do objeto `Date`. Após, faz a formatação de minutos e segundos para exibir "01" ao invés de apenas "1", por exemplo. Também é utilizado a função `setTimeout` do JavaScript para manter a contagem de tempo rodando.